# Why does this print out twice?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, graphics2d

I've noticed that when i use `paintComponent` in java if I use `System.out.println();` things will print out 2, 3, and sometimes 4 times. I know that when you use `extends JPanel` it will automatically be called, but why more then once.

Here is some code to try yourself.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class stack extends JPanel{
public stack(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    }
public static void main(String args[]){
    stack s = new stack();
    }
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.drawString("Thank You!", 100, 100);
    System.out.println("Why?");
}
}
```

Comment: It gets called every time the component is `repainted`, e.g. for frame resizes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out.println` gets called once - but your method could be called repeatedly. Everytime `paintComponent` is called it prints `Why?`.

This method is being called multiple times, ie, for frame resizes or such and in turn makes it appear that `sysout` is being executed more than once.